# withSuccessHandler returns null

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have `WebAppChart.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      function update() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) {
          console.log(ar);
        }).update();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And `Code.gs` file with functions:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('WebAppChart');
}

function update() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange(1, 1, 1, 2).getValues();
}
```

They work fine and return values from cells `A1` and `B1`. Console output, as expected:
[image]

But when I increase the number of rows, for example:

```
function update() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange(1, 1, 2, 2).getValues();
}
```

It returns `null`, console output:

[image]

But I expect to see the values of `A1:B2`. How can I fix this? The sheet contains data in row 2.

Comment: About `But when I increase the number of rows, for example, getRange(1, 1, 2, 2) returns null.`, I think that when you modify `return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange(1, 1, 2, 2).getValues();` and update your Web Apps, the values of "A1:B2" are returned. So, unfortunately, I cannot understand your situation. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Tanaike You are right, the only change in the code is the number `1` (number of rows) changes to `2`. I edited the question to make it easier to understand. After making the changes, I save the changes, do a test deployment and refresh the page with the test link.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In the case of `return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange(1, 1, 2, 2).getValues();`, I think that the values from "A1:B2" are returned as an array. And, you can see it with ` console.log(ar);`. In this case, even when the cells "A1:B2" are empty, I think that the empty 2-dimensional array is returned. I think that the returned value is not null. How about this? If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: I thought that when I could correctly replicate your current situation, I might be able to find a modification point. But, in the current stage, I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike thank you for your help. This is essentially all the code I used. If you create a table with four values `A1:B2` and copy the code I wrote above you can replicate it. I updated the post with console screenshots.

Comment: I have added in the post all the code needed to replicate the issue. If you create a table with four values `A1:B2` and copy the code I wrote above you can reproduce it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I have added in the post all the code needed to replicate the issue.`, I think that in your HTML, `update()` is not run. So, I'm worried that even null is not returned. But, you say `If you create a table with four values A1:B2 and copy the code I wrote above you can reproduce it.`. From this situation, I'm confused about your question. I apologize for this.

Comment: Unfortunately, from your updated script, I cannot still replicate your situation. I apologize for my poor skill. I would like to believe `I have added in the post all the code needed to replicate the issue. If you create a table with four values A1:B2 and copy the code I wrote above you can reproduce it.`. So, I would like to try to replicate your situation.
 When I could correctly replicate your situation from your current showing script, I would like to think of a modification point. I deeply apologize that I cannot replicate your situation soon.

Comment: From your headers `['DATE", 'Etherium']` if column A are Date objects you can not return a Date you need to return its value or as a string.  See [.myFunction()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withUserObject(Object))